# How would separate projects share EF DbContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

How should I break out a project, with the ability to share the EF `DbContext`.

This is a new project, and the idea was to have something like this:

```
Appname.Common

Appname.Models

Appname.Service1
Appname.Service2

Appname.Web
```

Now with the above VS.NET 2012 solution, I am currently planning on having repositories for each service project, but how will I share the EF context around between the 2 services?

What options do I have?

Note: both `Service1` and `Service2` are using the same database

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to share repositories across the services?

Comment: one solution, >= three projects: Models, Service1, Service2, others. You can access Models as a simple dll.

Comment: I assume you define the DbContext inside the **Appname.Models** project.  Why don't Service1 and Service2 both simply reference that project?

Comment: @danihp so you are also saying to have the dbcontext in models then also correct? along with repositories?

Comment: Create a project with the DbContext and helper functions, then include that project in your service applications?

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you inject the `DbContext`, using [DI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), into your repositories?

Comment: Have a look at using something like Ninject, or StructureMap.